# ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID, 404 not found, localhost:8000

Tags: python, flask, localhost

I don't really know where to start and also don't really know where the issue comes from that's why I couldn't find a precise title for this question. Here is my problem.

I copied this code from github, as part of a tutorial to learn about API's :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/readHello')
def getRequestHello():
    return "Hi, I got your GET Request!"

@app.route('/createHello', methods = ['POST'])
def postRequestHello():
    return "I see you sent a POST message :-)"


@app.route('/updateHello', methods = ['PUT'])
def updateRequestHello():
    return "Sending Hello on an PUT request!"


@app.route('/deleteHello', methods = ['DELETE'])
def deleteRequestHello():
    return "Deleting your hard drive.....haha just kidding! I received a DELETE request!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I installed a virtual machine with vagrant and it runs perfectly. When I try to run this code in the machine(I tried on my local machine and have the same issue), the terminal returns this :

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ python api_server.py
 * Serving Flask app "api_server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 203-304-000
```

So I try to access the page on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ but I get this error "ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID". When I try with http://127.0.0.1:8000 (not sure what the difference is but I found that it worked for some people) I get another error, this time 404 page not found.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add "/" route listening

```
@app.route('/')
def getMainRequest():
    return "Hi, Server is running fine!"
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer ! It worked with the adress 127.0.0.1:8000 but only on the surface, as it returned the sentence Hi, Server is running fine, but when I try to send api requests other than get I get errors as I did before

Comment: I think you are not accessing correctly the apis
Check with curl it wil give correct response

```
    curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/readHello
    curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/createHello
    curl -X PUT http://localhost:8000/updateHello
    curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8000/deleteHello
```

Comment: this article will help you understand the flask 
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/quickstart/